# Probability of A given B and probability of A given B complement.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I would like to know the relation between probability of A given B and probability of A given B complement. Could you please provide the explanation and the proof?

Here is a relation I was able to infer on my own so far:

$$
P(A|B') = \frac {P(A)-P(B)P(A|B)}{1 - P(B)}
$$

I hope for an easier one.

Comment: in what context ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, there is no context in my question. I would like to know the relation in general.

Comment: okay well you're lucky it's not necessarily context dependent, because some things are.  either b happens or the complement of b happens 100% of the time in a two case scenario like this.  so they sum to the probability of A under 100% of the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$P(A \cap B)+P(A \cap B')=P(A)$$

we have,

$$P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B')P(B')=P(A)$$

Comment: Could you please show more precisely why the first statement holds? Even though I get it intuitively.

Comment: Oh! It seems I got the case. Is it because of the mutual exclusion and we can apply the third axiom here?

Comment: $A \cap B$ and $A \cap B'$ are disjoint and their union is $A$.

Comment: @ohidano If you replace your $1-P(B)$ with $P(B')$, then this is exactly the same as your formula,